# RestTemplate not returning full response

Tags: xml, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I am using spring boot to call a rest service that returns XML string.
if I call the service from postman it returns the correct xml string , which is similar to this (shortened for simplicity):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RateResponse>
    <RateQueryResponses>
        <rateQueryResponseList>
            <carrierCode>CUST</carrierCode>
            <mode>SLTL</mode>
            < ... more content here .... >
            <declaredValue>0.0</declaredValue>
            <routingGuideLane>
                <destLocType></destLocType>
                <frequency></frequency>
                <laneDest></laneDest>
                <origLocType></origLocType>
            </routingGuideLane>
            <routingGuideLaneCarrierDetails>
                <capacityVolume>0</capacityVolume>
                <carrierCode>CUST</carrierCode>
                <rank></rank>
                <tier></tier>
            </routingGuideLaneCarrierDetails>
            <totalRevenue>
                <rate>0.0</rate>
                <revenueAccessorialList>
                    <accessorialCode>FUEL</accessorialCode>
                    <accessorialRevenue>0.0</accessorialRevenue>
                    <approved>true</approved>
                    <calculationMethod>PCT</calculationMethod>
                    <minimumRate>0.0</minimumRate>
                    <payeeCarrierId>-2147483648</payeeCarrierId>
                    <rate>0.735</rate>
                </revenueAccessorialList>
                <revenueAccessorialList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                <revenueAccessorialList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                <stopOffRevenue>0.0</stopOffRevenue>
                <totalAccessorialRevenue>0.0</totalAccessorialRevenue>
            </totalRevenue>
        </rateQueryResponseList>
    </RateQueryResponses>
</RateResponse>
```

the problem I am having when I call this service from spring boot, is that it returns the full xml except the `<revenueAccessorialList>` elements.
This element is supposed to repeat (it is a list) but for some unknown reason the vendor who supports the service is returning first element in the list and then 2 null elements (as you can see  `<revenueAccessorialList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>`

I don't mind if I don't get the null elements, but I am not getting the first one either from spring boot.

This is the code I am using: (I tried postForEntity and exchange)

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));

HttpEntity<QueryRequest> requestlEntity = new HttpEntity<>(rreq, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> qrlEntity = null;
return restTemplate.exchange(serviceEp, HttpMethod.POST, requestlEntity, String.class);
//  return restTemplate.postForEntity(serviceEp, requestlEntity, String.class);
```

Both methods return the full xml without those elements.
Any ideas? is there anything I can try other than restTemplate with springboot?

As I mentioned, this works fine from postman and returns the full string

Thank you

Comment: Are you actually watching the String value from restTemplate call? Or the xml is mapped to some object and you found `revenueAccessorialList` is not mapped?

Comment: I am trying to get the raw string value. I don't have it mapped to any object because I need to store the xml string as is in the database